# how to prevent an error from breaking a loop

Tags: linux, bash, loops, error-handling, break

if a string contains less than the number of characters you're trying to remove with this command:
(4 characters in this example)

```
variable1=${string::-4}
```

and this command is within a loop,the error causes the loop to break

is there anyway to prevent the loop from breaking, without first running a command to check if the string has more  than 4 characters?

..like a "ignore error and continue anyway" command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely a side-effect of using `set -e` or `set -o errexit` to exit on error.

You cannot prevent this string indexation to throw an error if the index is invalid for the input string.

So you have to actually check the index will be valid within the string like:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -o errexit

for string in 'Hello abcd' '42' 'worldfour' '!here'; do
  if [ ${#string} -ge 4 ]; then
    variable1=${string::-4}
  else
    variable1=
  fi
  printf '%s' "$variable1"
done
echo
```